# Backbone.js Pushstate Routing and PHP Framework's Router

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using Backbone.js along with a PHP MVC framework (Codeigniter, Laravel). I'm confused about how URLs will be handled by the PHP router and Backbone router when using Pushstates. (I have not started using pushstates yet, still using hashbangs `#`). I am not working on a single-page-application, but rather the site is made up of several pages that act like single-page-application on its own.

**Problem:** If I have a page `http://domain.com/user/user123`, and clicking a link `http://domain.com/user/user123#photos` loads some photos via AJAX and I want to get rid of the `#`, I forsee the problem where a user who goes to `http://domain.com/user/user123/photos` after clicking on the link decides to copy and paste the URL into another browser tab will see an error 404 page as the PHP framework router *(if I assume correctly that the PHP router handles the URL request first before backbone's)* does not recognize the existence of this url. How should this problem be solved?

Another problem I think will arise, is how should the view be rendered when the user goes to `http://domain.com/user/user123/photos` directly? Should the HTML code be duplicated on both the PHP View (for the instance where the user enters the URL directly) and the backbone.js View (for the case where the user clicks on the link from `http://domain.com/user/user123`)? This does not seem like the optimal solution to me. Or can the View somehow be rendered in both cases by backbone to avoid duplicate code?

Please advise :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've hit on one of the more challenging aspects of incorporating `pushState` into a backbone app. Basically, you need to make sure that any route you'll be linking to within your app can also be handled by the server.

The easiest way to solve this, in PHP, is to route all requests for valid URLs (`/user/user123`) to your root page, and then let backbone call the handler corresponding to the url fragment. This requires you on the server side to actually know what a valid URL is (i.e. `/posts/5` is valid, `/posts/abc` or `/aaa/` is not, etc.), but otherwise it's not a huge amount of work.

Ultimately the problem is that you're switching between a stateless protocol (HTTP) and a state-ful application (backbone.js). This requires some careful planning.

Regarding your second question, you don't need to render the view on the server-side, just do everything you would do for a request to the root domain and backbone.js will trigger the appropriate handler (e.g. `/user/user123`). The only case where you'd want to actually render the view on the server side is if you want to support users without javascript, or make your app RESTful, in which case you would have to duplicate view code (there is no easy way around this).

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, how should I let PHP handle something like `/user/user123/posts/456`?

Comment: Basically you should respond to any valid request in the exact same way you would for a request to the root `/`. Let backbone handle the routing after that.

Comment: Actually come to think of it, if you're working in PHP then you probably want to do this routing directly in apache or whatever HTTP server you're using. I was thinking in terms of rails where it's easy to define a bunch of routes that all point to the same root page.

Comment: How would u do this in Rails? My framework has Sinatra-style routing, like `Route::get('/users/(:any)', function($id) { doSomething(); });`

Comment: In rails I just define a resource, `resources :users`, and then define controller actions for whatever I want to handle, so e.g.: `show` (`GET /user/user123`), `new` (`GET /user/new'), `edit` (`GET /user/user123/edit`), etc. The functions don't do anything because all I need is the layout, the rest is appended to the page by backbone. I also define blank views for each action, otherwise rails throws an error, but they are empty.

Comment: Basically whatever you have in the `doSomething()` for your root action is what you should put in the other routes you want to handle. Which is probably nothing, or almost nothing -- in my case all that rails does is to render the layout and then hand off to backbone. Everything else is does via ajax requests/responses (JSON).