# Backbone pushState and Laravel 4 - Routes won't work

Tags: backbone.js, laravel, laravel-4

I've got a very simple setup of laravel 4 with 1 controller for trips.
Now another simple setup of Backbone with a Router and routes to regular routes like `trips`, `trips/create`. I want to use pushState: true to have nice URL but I can't seem to get it to work. When I try to reach the URLs it sends me to the page served by the server with my json data.

However, if I type: `www.mysite.com/#trips` I am "redirected" to `www.mysite.com/trips` and then my method for this specific route triggers.

Here's my Router:

```
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    '': 'index',
    'trips':            'trips',
    'trips/create':     'newTrip',
    'trips/:id':        'showTrip'
},

index: function(){

},

trips: function(){
    console.log('All trips') ;
},

newTrip: function(){

    console.log('New trip') ;

},

showTrip: function(id){
    console.log('trips id:' + id) ;
}
});
```

Comment: is your pushState enabled ?

Comment: Yes. I have history.start({ pushState: true });

Comment: have you done the server side aspect of `pushState`? All the routes must be known by the server too. Here is another question about this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731998/backbone-js-pushstate-routing-and-php-frameworks-router

Comment: I have all the routes handled by laravel. I can access them in the browser when I input them directly

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by the Backbone router not being able to match the URL to your Backbone routes. To debug, add this to your routes:

```
'*actions':                 'defaultAction'
```

Then in the router add:

```
defaultAction: function(path) {
    console.log('Route "' + path + '" not defined, redirecting to homepage!');
}
```

You will probably see that the path is different from anything in your routes. To fix this, you need to tell Backbone the root of your paths. You do this while activating pushstates.

```
Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: true,
    root: 'http://mydomain.com/myapplication/'
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think laravel 4 (for sure) is the first to read the request and because it tries to find a route matching before loading backbone from "/" route. I already have what you want me to do but; when i go to */#login for example, backbone replaces it with */login. And when I hit return / enter to reload; I am facing with Whoops!. A good reason to have links is to let people share them. Not to achive history events only. Isn't it?