# Backbone home route reloads page

Tags: backbone.js, router

in a very simple backbone app, I tried manipulating routes, I have them working, but I'm just wondering why the links to the homepage actually reload the page, when no other routes do reload.

Here's my router:

```
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    '':             'index',
    'trips':        'trips',
    'trips/new':    'newTrip',
    'trips/:id':    'showTrip'
},

index: function(){

    App.trips = new App.Collections.Trips ;

    App.trips.fetch().then(function(){

        new App.Views.App({ collection: App.trips });

    });
},

trips: function(){
    console.log('All trips') ;
},

newTrip: function(){
    console.log('new trip') ;
    var new_trip = new App.Views.Trip.New ;

    $('#content').empty().append(new_trip.el) ;

},

showTrip: function(id){
    console.log('trips id:' + id) ;
}
});
```

Comment: What do the links look like, how are they constructed? If they're in view code, what can you include that snippet of code?

Comment: Have you added event handlers to prevent the default behavior and call 'Backbone.history.navigate(...)`? Links will behave as normal unless you explicitly do something else.

Comment: @StuartM my home link is purely: `<a href="./">Home</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a Backbone router or a link you must be aware of the fact that every route is handled with the `#` as long as you have not enabled pushstate (on your browser and server).

So if you need to set a link to home use `#`

like `<a class="brand" href="#/">Home</a>` otherwise the link is handled as a native url

Comment: thanks for that. it works with `href="#/"`. Now I tried to use pushState but somehow it doesn't work. I use Laravel 4 as a backend and Chrome as a browser. Isn't it supposed to work? If you could have a look at my question here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498793/backbone-pushstate-and-laravel-4-routes-wont-work